# Is there any way to call initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath with some delay consecutively for collection view cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am working on a UICollectionView that reload the cells animatedly.
I have wrote an animation code in my layout class in

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath
```

And its works perfectly i just want to know is that somehow can i introduce an delay in cells animations so it will be like first cell reaches its place than second and then third cell and so far.

So is there any specific way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the framework is not designed to work in that way. I would not animate the frames directly – that is a dark path that leads to pain. You'd basically need to add one model to the data source backing the collection view, wait, and repeat. It shouldn't be too hard, but it is a bit hacky.

Comment: This method is definitely less Hacky than mine. I would go with this one.

Comment: @Ash Finally I achieved that by changing reload to manually inserting items with some delay. Is that what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 1):

If the appearance animation you'd like to achieve is a frame animation you can adjust the initial start position instead of adding a delay.

Let's say you want your cells to fly in from the right. For the first cell you can set the initial offset to 500px, for the second 600px for the third 700px and so on. Even though they all start animating at the same time, they'll reach their positions in succession.

Hope this helps.